# how to solve android google signing issue which is not working after publishing app on play store?

Tags: android, google-signin

Google plus signin is not working after publishing app on play store. It works fine on my debugging mobile device. How to solve it?

Comment: Did you switch to an API key tied to your release certificate?

Comment: @Chris Stratton how to do this same issue arise here

Answer (score 1):

you doesn't attach your *SHA-1 certificate fingerprint* on **"Google Developer Consol"** at *OAuth 2.0 client IDs* .So go on Google developer Consol first and add your SHA-1 fingerprint in both API KEY and OAuth 2.0 client IDs. Perhaps you have added fingerprint in API KEY but not in OAuth 2.0 client IDs.

So follow below path:

1 ): Open your **Google developer consol.**

2 ): Go on side menu bar and click to **API MANAGER.**

3 ): Click on **Credentials.**

4 ): Now Click on **Create Credentials.**

5 ): Select to **OAuth Client ID** and your **release SHA-1 fingerprint.**