# Google Sign In not working after published in playstore

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, google-plus, google-signin

Before publishing in the play store my google sign was working fine. I saw some questions here in stackoverflow, but none of them answered my question. I don't know why the login is not working anymore. (I'm not using firebase).

I did all the steps to make the google sign work, and it was working before I published. Anyone knows what is happening? What can I do?

Comment: Are you using the same debug key for the released version too? Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18495075/google-play-services-sign-in-client-id-debug-vs-release

Comment: I don't know how to check it, I think I'm using the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is due to different SHA1 keys for debug and release version.

The thing is that for google sign in you must add SHA1 key in your google account which you can get from programming or from command prompt.

SHA1 key is different for signed apk. So you have two SHA1, one each for debug and release version. The SHA1 for release version can be obtained from keystore file.

if you want to read more about this you can check this [link](http://devdeeds.com/create-sha1-key-using-android-studio/). It is very well explained there.

Comment: i agree with you @Rucha Bhatt

Comment: Did you check that link which i mention above? @Felipe

Comment: Also, go to Released Management->App Signing on Play Console to copy Google Play release SHA-1 to your firebase.

Answer (score -1):

As per @Jan Lovšin stated, maybe you're using same `.keystore` for your debug and release APKs. Be noted that you need to create two key store - debug.keystore(for debug) and release.keystore (for publish application). You may follow this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40830417/5832311) for detailed explanation. You may also check on this related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36014812/how-to-solve-android-google-signing-issue-which-is-not-working-after-publishing). Hope this helps!