# Google Play Games Services cannot login after published the game

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-games, google-play-console

Google Play Games Services cannot log in after published the game, is it because I didn't use firebase? Or firebase is needed for Google Play Games Services?

I already replace the old SHA1 with copied SHA1(from "Upload certificate"), and it only works before publishing the game.

Answer (score 2):

SHA1 keys are different for both debug and release version.

This could be the main reason.

This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41029903/google-sign-in-not-working-after-published-in-playstore/41034093) pointed out about the issue:

> SHA1 key is different for signed apk. So you have two SHA1, one each
>   for debug and release version. The SHA1 for release version can be
>   obtained from keystore file.

You can learn more [here](http://devdeeds.com/create-sha1-key-using-android-studio/) about the difference of two SHA1 version and how to obtain it.

You can also try to have a look on this SO posts:

- [Google Sign In Service not working after publish on PlayStore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46304414/google-sign-in-service-not-working-after-publish-on-playstore?rq=1)
- [Google sign in not working after publishing in play store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39318370/google-sign-in-not-working-after-publishing-in-play-store)